# Laravel MessageBag errors array is empty in view but with content if I kill script

Tags: validation, laravel

I am trying to return errors back to my view, this is part of my controller TestcategoryController

```
    $rules =array(
        'name' => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    //process
    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('testcategory/create')->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

In the view `testcategory/create` if I try and output the errors like

```
        @if($errors->any())         
            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
        @endif
```

I get nothing. But if I `{{dd($errors)}}` I get

```
      object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#91 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(1) { 
      ["default"]=> object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#92 (2) 
      { ["messages":protected]=>   array(1) 
      { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "The name field is required." } }  
      ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message" } } }
```

The only way I am getting the errors is if I kill the script. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get nothing in your case, than it means you have overridden your $errors object with something else or with empty object - check your code and data you pass to the views. Your code is perfectly valid and works good - I've tested it locally. Maybe, you passed empty $errors object to your subview, but in other views the correct object is used.

Comment: It seems using a custom submit function overrides the error bag.

Comment: @briankip I am setting a form field values via Javascript on `click` method of button. Is this the reason I am not getting it too?

Comment: Most likely. But I would have to see the code to confirm.

Answer (score 9):

Probably another issue would be with $errors not being saved to Session variable  $errors and nothing being shown in the view.

Here is an example of the same issue:
http://laravel.io/forum/03-28-2016-errors-variable-empty-after-failed-validation

For me the solution defined in the above link worked.
Solution: Is in app\Http\Kernel.php
Move 
`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` from $middlewareGroups to $middleware

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: AWESOME, you just resolved my problem! Thanks buddy :)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but I my case the problem remains after I switch the Session Middleware between the variables. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it like this:

```
{{ $errors->getBag('default')->first('name') }}
```

Comment: If I dump this it show the error, but it does not show in the view if I don't dump and kill the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    });
```

Add middleware, and resolved..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Laravel 8.0

The only way I could solve this was by entering the error bags layer by layer until I got to the messages manually:

```
@if (count($errors->getBags()))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->getBags() as $bag)
                @foreach ($bag->getMessages() as $messages)
                    @foreach ($messages as $message)
                        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - I was not getting error messages in my views.
I was helped by setting the `SESSION_DRIVER=file` setting in my .env file. Prior to this, the value 'cookies' was specified.