# Laravel 4.2 custom validation messages in language file

Tags: validation, laravel, message

I have code in my controller like this:

```
    $validator = Validator::make(
        Input::only('first_name', 'last_name'),
        array(
            'first_name' => 'required|min:1|max:20',
            'last_name'  => 'required|min:1|max:20',
        )
    );

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        Input::flashOnly('first_name', 'last_name');

        return Redirect::route('admin.partner.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator, 'partner');
    }
```

Language is set correctly.

In my language file I have rules:

```
'partner' => array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'required' => 'My message here',
    ),
),
```

I try to output my message like this:

```
{{ $errors->partner->first('first_name') }}
```

but instead of my custom message it still outputs me main message from language file

```
...
"required"             => "The :attribute field is required.",
...
```

Maybe, I'm mistaken, but if I pass `->withErrors($validator, 'partner')` (having set `partner` as my custom errors array), I should receive first message from my custom array using `$errors->partner->first('first_name')`, but not from general errors array?

Comment: have you tried `->withErrors($validator);`

Comment: Tried, of course. But I need custom errors, not standard. And in case I do not add `'partner'` param, I can not access my message like `$errors->partner->first('first_name')`

Comment: I am new to this, am not even at custom validators, the default ones are giving me a headache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323190/laravel-messagebag-errors-array-is-empty-in-view-but-with-content-if-i-kill-scri

Answer (score 0):

As in the docs, you need to have a `'custom'` key in your array, because Laravel will try to find custom keys first:

```
'custom' => array(
    'partner' => array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'required' => 'My message here',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: This does not work either. I still get standard errors instead of custom errors.