# validate function not working in laravel form validation Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, helper

Here the **signin** function is working fine but **$this->validate()** function returns nothing in view page. tried various method suggested in other Q&As. seems something wrong with helpers.

### userController

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'bail|required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]); 


    if (Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'] ])){
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

### Login Page

```
 @if ($errors->any())
                            <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <li>{{$error}}</li>
                                        @endforeach  
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <form name="loginForm" action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="post"  autocomplete="disable">

                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('email')? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder=" " />
                                <label for="loginFormInputEmail">Email address</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control  {{ $errors->has('password')? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                <label for="loginFormInputPassword">Password</label>
                            </div>
```

Comment: what errors do you get in console? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This code looks ok to me. Try to add a random rule (like 'min:666' for example) and test.

Comment: i'm getting no error in console, and i'm trying to display the errors in view page from login input validation. code seems to look fine but still getting nothing in return. could be any helpers related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably another issue would be with $errors not being saved to Session variable $errors and nothing being shown in the view.

Here is an example of the same issue: http://laravel.io/forum/03-28-2016-errors-variable-empty-after-failed-validation

For me the solution defined in the above link worked. Solution: Is in app\Http\Kernel.php Move \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, from $middlewareGroups to $middleware

**Before**

[image]

**After**
[image]

**Source Thrade**
:  [Laravel MessageBag errors array is empty in view but with content if I kill script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36674614/5506634)